# Tagging docker image remotely

Tags: docker

The current process I have for tagging an image in the same registry is below:

```
docker pull image:1
docker tag image:1 image:2
docker push image:2
```

Is there a way for this to be done without having to pull down the image before tagging. Would be "seamless" if I was able to refer to an image, tag and push to the reg in less steps.

Answer (score 1):

According a Docker guy in [this post](https://forums.docker.com/t/tag-without-pull-push/12836/2) from Docker forums, it's not possible. Also:

> If the layers already exist and you docker push with a different tag
>   Docker will figure out there is nothing to push and report Layer
>   already exists for those layers.

Comment: Thanks for that. As per that post, it seems that their use case it to tag between two registries. Hence it sounds uncomfortable because one reg would need to have access/know off the other reg. In my case, where both images would live in the same reg, would it have the same problem?

Comment: I think so. It would make sense. There would be two images with same layers and two different tags in the same registry and repository... Docker won't allow that. They are the same images after all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the small helper tool "crane" for remotely changing manifests in a container image registry. The command looks like this to add the tag "2" to the source image with tag "1":

```
crane tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:1 2
```

In case you don't want to use an extra tool and already have curl at hand, there are also ways to forge all required HTTP requests to the registry manually to add the tag. There are some tutorials out there that explain that.